# Convergence of $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \le Cq^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Be $C\gt 0$, $0\le q\lt 1$ and $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with
$$|a_{n+1} - a_n| \le Cq^n$$
Show that $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ converges.

Comment: **Hint:** Prove $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: A sequence is a cauchy sequence if $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N_\epsilon > 0$ such that $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$  $\forall n, m > N_\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>m$ we have
$$
|a_n-a_m|\le\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}|a_i-a_{i+1}|\le C\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}q^i=C\frac{q^m-q^{(n-1)-m+1}}{1-q}\le C\frac{q^m}{1-q}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{m,n\to \infty}|a_n-a_m|\le \lim_{m,n\to\infty}C\frac{q^m}{1-q}=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
\lim_{m,n\to \infty}|a_n-a_m|=0.
$$
Hence $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, consequently it converges.