# show that sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. If $$|a_{n+1} − a_n | ≤ \frac{1}{2}\  |a_n − a_{n−1} |,  \qquad \forall n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$$
then show that $(a_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570989/convergence-of-a-n1-a-n-le-cqn).

Answer (score 4):

First step: $$|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a_2 - a_1|$$

Second step:

$$|a_n - a_m| \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}|a_{k+1} - a_k| \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}|a_2 - a_1| \leq |a_2 - a_1|\sum_{k=m}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}} = \dfrac{|a_2 - a_1|}{2^{m-2}}$$

Now conclude $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, so it converges

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a_2-a_1|$$

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is sufficiently accurate for $a_n$ = $\sum^n_{i=1} 1/i$

Comment: @Pieter21 Yes, you are very correct. I did not show that it is a Cauchy sequence, as I should. I will leave only the hint.